# How to Wait for Asynch Firebase Call in Main Thread (Swift)

Tags: swift, firebase, asynchronous, firebase-storage, grand-central-dispatch

**Background:**

I am using a library called `KolodaView` which generates Tinder-esque cards for Swift applications. The Cards are rendered during the `viewDidLoad()` function of my view controller after assigning the delegate. I wrote the `viewForCardAt()` delegate function so that for every card that is rendered, a call to `getPics()` is made that sets a global variable `imageResult: UIImageView` containing a `UIImageView` (Note: The `UIView` that is returned from `viewForCardAt()` is the actual `UIView` that will be placed on the card).

**The Issue:**

`getPics()` makes a call to fire base (`storageRef.getData()`) and as a result is asynchronous. Because `viewForCardAt()` **must** return something (as it goes through generating the cards) and is running on the main thread, it cannot wait or be 'notified' when the `getPics()`function is completed. Not being able to wait results in the rendered cards having no image, as `getPics()` hasn't finished fetching data before `viewForCardAt()` returns its `UIView`.

**What I Have Tried:**

Using dispatch group wait, but since both of these calls are happening on the main thread, adding a wait statement in either the Koloda `viewForCardAt()` function or even the `getPics()` function freezes the entire app. I thought about somehow putting the `getPics` in a different, asynch, thread, but then `viewForCardAt()` would still have to wait on `getPics()` completion as it cannot return until `getPics()` has 'returned its value' (assigned its value to the global reference).

**Relevant Code (Abstracted)**

```
myViewController() {

    var imageResult: UIImageView

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.kolodaView.delegate = self
    }

    .
    .
    .

    func getPics() {
        grabImageDispatchGroup.enter()
        let storage = Storage.storage
        let storageRef = storage.reference(forURL: photoLink)
        //the asynch firebase call
        storageRef.getData(....) { (data, error) in
            //the actual result of the query being stored
            //for the Koloda card to use on the current card
            self.imageResult.image = UIImage(data: data)
            grabImageDispatchGroup.leave()
        }
    }

    //run for element in a specified 'user' array ("dataSource" stuff not shown for brevity) 
    func Koloda(_ koloda: KolodaView, viewForCardAt index: Int) -> UIView {

        var cardView = UIView()
        getPics()
        grabImageDispatchGroup.notify() { //this cannot work since we must return a value
            cardView.addSubview(imageResult)
            return cardView
        }

        //invalid: 'this function must return something'
    }

}
```

Comment: Typically, cases like these are handled with a placeholder view, like a loading indicator, while the actual data is fetched

Comment: have you tried async await https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await

Comment: @NewDev the issue with this is, I won't be able to go back and change the card once I assign it its UIView (at least from what I understand)

Comment: @jaibalaji I am programming in Swift not JavaScript?

Comment: You have to refactor your design, you cannot return something from an asynchronous task. By the way you are misusing `DispatchGroup` anyway. The API is for multiple asynchronous requests for example in a loop.

Comment: @vadian what would be the appropriate API to use then in cases like this?

Comment: A completion handler like in jawadAli’s answer.

Comment: @vadian I cannot do this, I think because this function is a delegate function, and when I try to add completion:@escaping it says "escaping type only applies to function types"

Comment: As I said you have to refactor your design to handle the asynchronous data processing.

Comment: @vadian I refactored my code, but am now running into an issue where I have a loop of network calls (all appending their callback data to a global array), and am correctly using a dispatch group to not leave the function until all network calls are done (until the group's enters/leaves are balanced). However, I have no control over the order in which the callbacks edit the global array, and am getting random orderings in the data. How do I ensure these callbacks, all occurring in separate threads, run serially to keep an ordering in the global array?

Answer (score 1):

Use completion handler instead of return

```
func Koloda(_ koloda: KolodaView, viewForCardAt index: Int , completion:@escaping (UIView) -> Void )  {

    var cardView = UIView()
    getPics()
    grabImageDispatchGroup.notify() { //this cannot work since we must return a value
        cardView.addSubview(imageResult)
        return completion( cardView)
    }

    //invalid: 'this function must return something'
}
```